# How to setup TOR as a network interface for VMs on Mac OS Mojave?

Tags: networking, macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, tor

I am using VirtualBox and Whonix to create a secure way of letting a VM communicate only through TOR. However, I would like to setup TOR on the host Mac OS as a network interface so it can be selected as network device in the VirtualBox VM config. This way the Whonix workaround is not required anymore. The VM will only have one network device and that communicates through TOR only.

I can't find anyone having the same requirement. Maybe I am trying something nonsense?

EDIT:
Another way could be to have a virtual network interface / device that only communicates through a proxy. Setting up a TOR proxy is no problem - it is f.i. pre-configured and included in the TOR browser bundle. However, I also couldn't find a way to create a proxy based network device.

Thanks

Comment: Don't do this. It is not a "workaround" to have the Whonix-Gateway in a separate virtual machine. It's a very important part of the security design.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I understand your point. I am not trying to workaround the Whonix gateway per se, but I would like to ensure that also Windows or other Unix VMs will only communicate through TOR. (Altough, I admit, I pointed out in my question it's all about saving a VM)